# In keyword not working properly in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on SQL Server 2008 R2.

The following query:

```
select alloted_area 
from tbllogin 
where nid = 82
```

returns this

```
alloted_area
1,101,1002,79,365,297
```

The following query

```
select * 
from tblarea 
where nid in (1, 101, 1002, 79, 365, 297)
```

returns this

```
nid     area_name
------------------
1       RAJASTHAN
101     RAJASTHAN
79      RAJASTHAN
297     RAJASTHAN
365     RAJASTHAN
1002    RAJASTHAN
```

But the following query

```
select * 
from  tblarea 
where nid in (select alloted_area from tbllogin where nid = 82)
```

generates this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   '1,101,1002,79,365,297' to data type int

What should I do?

Perhaps I have to make rows out of `alloted_areas` in `tbllogin` on the basis of comma sign. How do I do that?

As suggested in the comments I did try not to store data as comma separated values but that would mean creating an entire table to store that information. So is there any way I can achieve the desired result in my situation.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: `IN` is working properly. What you are doing is the equivalent of `nid = cast( '1,101,1002,79,365,297' as int)`, which of course doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(max) = (select alloted_area from tbllogin where nid = 82)
select * from  tblarea where nid in (select sID from splitstring(@values,','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @values NVARCHAR(100) = (select alloted_area from tbllogin where nid = 82)
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(200) = ' select *  from  tblarea  where nid in ( '+ @values +' ) '
EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: it returns this error Could not find stored procedure ' select *  from  tblarea  where nid in ( 1,101,1002,79,365,297 ) '.

Comment: Change `EXEC @sqlQuery` to put brackets around the variable: `EXEC (@sqlQuery)`

Comment: Yea, beanfrog said is true. sorry i forgot the paren. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 different methods without involving a variable:
The SplitString is a new feature for sqlserver 2016, so I included a method to implement StringSplit for sqlserver 2008.

First method will work as long as nid in the table tbllogin is unique:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  tblarea 
WHERE
  nid in 
    (
      SELECT Value
      FROM
        [SplitString]((SELECT alloted_area FROM tbllogin WHERE nid = 82),',')
    )
```

Second method is able to handle situations when nid in table tbllogin is not unique:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  tblarea 
WHERE
  nid in 
  (
    SELECT x.value
    FROM tbllogin
    CROSS APPLY 
      [SplitString](alloted_area,',')x
   WHERE nid = 82
)
```

You can use this function to imitate StringSplit in sqlserver 2008:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( 
        SELECT 
          [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

nId is an int type. It looks like alloted_area is varchar type. Cross check.

Answer (score -1):

This might be because the type int is not declared correctly in your sub-select statement. This is where the `cast()` method works well.

Try: `cInt(alloted_area) AS alloted_area_int`

`select * from  tblarea where nid in (select cInt(alloted_area) AS alloted_area_int from tbllogin where nid=82)`